# How do I register a custom Django user model to the admin page?

Tags: python, django, django-models, web-applications, django-authentication

I followed a tutorial on how to allow Django authentication by using email instead of the normal username, however, they didn't mention how to register the new custom user model with the admin page! I am a real beginner to Django so I would appreciate as much detail as possible! Here is my code so far:

**managers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email field is required')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from .managers import CustomUserManager

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. ''Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.get_full_name()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
```

Comment: you need to import your model first then , admin.site.register(Yourcustommodel)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this code in your admin.py

We can register our models with [register](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#the-register-decorator) decorator.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CustomUser

@admin.register(CustomUser)
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from .models import CustomUser
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email',...) # add fields as you want

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!